# Where is my Chef data bag item?

Tags: chef-infra, knife, databags

I was trying to create a Chef data bag from within the chef-repo directory using the command:

```
knife data bag create users deployer
```

And i get the response:

```
Created data_bag[users]
Created data_bag_item[deployer]
```

But I am not able to locate the data bag *users* nor its data bag item. It is not in the data_bags folder or anywhere else that I could see. If I do a

```
knife data bag show users
```

It will show me the data bag item name. So it must be saved somewhere. The documentations tell me that the data bag should be in the folder **chef-repo -> data_bags -> users**. But my data_bags folder appears to be empty. So where is the data bag I have just created?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Chef, there's a disparity between your local computer (called the "workstation") and the remote Chef Server. In your case, the `knife` command created the data bag on the **remote Chef Server**.

I understand how that can be misleading. A data bag is nothing more than a folder containing one or more `.json` files. Usually you generate this structure manually on your workstation (either using the GUI or terminal).

So in your example, just make the folder you've described (`chef-repo -> data_bags -> users`) and then create a `chef-repo/data_bags/users/deployer.json` file using the schema described by the cookbook.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I went back to reread the documentation and sure enough it does say "The create argument is used to add a data bag **to** the server". Somehow I missed that. In any case I have to say that for a Chef noob, it can be a little confusing.

Comment: All our docs our open source on GitHub. Chef's technical writer would love to hear that kind of feedback (@chefdocs on Twitter).

Answer (score 12):

When you use

> knife data bag create users deployer

knife creates that data bag on chef-server. It is not available on your local chef workstation. But you can download this data bag on local workstation. Just use the following command

> knife download data_bags

This command will download you data bag in *chef-repo/data_bags/users/deployer.json*
You can go there and directly update this JSON file. When you are done, do remember to upload this data bag again with "*knife upload .*"

Comment: Command `knife upload .` really helped me because I was not finding anywhere How I could upload my data bags to the server. And for some reason `knife data bag from file ... ` was not finding my databag